# how to use throw exception in mysql database connect

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, database-connection

I come across this:-

[PHP Error handling: die() Vs trigger_error() Vs throw Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063053/php-error-handling-die-vs-trigger-error-vs-throw-exception)

and understood that throw exception is better

How can i replace die and use throw exception here in this code:-

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_db = "localhost";
$database_db = "database";
$username_db = "root";
$password_db = "password";
$db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db) or die("Unable to connect with Database"); 
?>
```

Comment: Was asking myself the same thing. Thanks for posting this question :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
try
{
    if ($db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: i need to replace `die("Unable to connect with Database");` with your code? Also can you tell me what is `@$_POST['variable']`

Comment: You should replace your last line with this. @ - is enabling silent mode, no error will be echoed but still logged in your server's error.log file. I guess you know what `$_POST['variable']` is.

Comment: yes i do know that... thanks for the info :)

Comment: one more thing, as i have added the code in an include_db file for database connection... so what i should put in the area `//do something` because it just need to do connect or show the error...

Comment: You can leave that empty, if there's no error the execution will continue with code what is after the `try...catch` block.

Comment: see this file is my database connection file, which i include on every page of my website.... these codes are just to connect with the database other things i do on their respective pages.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, as I've said if there's no error PHP will continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: can i change this like this to get things done...

try
{
    if (!$db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db))
    {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }
    else
    {
        $db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db);
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;
}

Comment: Test it, I don't know if it would work. Which I'm sure of is that if there is no error the mysqli_connect function will be executed twice.

Answer (score 3):

It is documented here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: ok `$db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db) or die("Unable to connect with Database");`

I have to replace with this

`$db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
}`