# mysqli_connect faliure, same code not working in two different places

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
mail('some@email.com',$subject,'Beginning');
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('myremote.host.com','username','password','db_name');
mail('some@email.com',$subject,'Connected');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo mysqli_connect_error();
mail('some@eail.com',$subject,'Error in Connection');
exit();

}
```

I am trying to connect to this database. I use **mail()** as a way to debug. I get the first mail "Beginning" but I can't get the mail "connected".

The same code I used in one of my other pages and it works fine. Why I can't get it to work on this page ? what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen somebody using `mail()` as a debug tool... That is wrong on so many levels.

Comment: I've removed your email address and database connection information from your post, best not to post actual info like that.

Comment: Can you suggest any good debugging tools ?

Comment: How about using the error messages of mysqli? Have a look at the examples on [mysqli::error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: `die(var_dump($db_connection));` should do the trick. The result of your DB connection is stored in `$db_connection`.

Comment: try this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836693/how-to-use-throw-exception-in-mysql-database-connect

Comment: I use mysqli error messages. I don't get any reply.

Comment: I tried using or die. When I use it I stop getting emails at all. even the very first one before executing other code.

Comment: AirForce - don't rely on emails to do your debugging. Do it in the browser, or if you're using command line - rely on output from that. Emails depend on multiple servers to come through and you aren't actually using the result of your DB connection to determine what to send in your email - my main point here is stop using emails for debugging.