# Try / catch in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, try-catch

I'm following an OOP mysqli course. When connecting to the database, they use the following script:

```
$db = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
if ($db->connect_error){
    $error = $db->connect_error;
    echo("Not connected: " . $error);
}
```

Later though, they call the database connection file with a try / catch block:

```
try {
    require_once "connection.php";
}catch (Exception $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

Isn't a possible connection error being handled by the connection file immediately after trying to connect? Is the try / catch block basically doing the same thing? Or is the try / catch block looking for a different type of error?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, after reading some of the answers. When I just do this:

```
try {
    $db = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
}catch (Exception $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

assuming that the database access data is wrong (for example a wrong host), I get a PHP warning but not the error output in the catch block. Shouldn't the catch detect this error?

Comment: Please add a link to the course

Comment: If the connection file was throwing an exception, and if the catch block terminated the script after displaying any exception, I'd be inclined to agree.... but in reality nothing is actually handling any connection problem cleanly, because the script will continue executing regardless of whether it has a database connection or not

Comment: joebezucha, the course is called Accessing Databases with Object-Oriented PHP from lynda.com

Comment: http://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Accessing-Databases-Object-Oriented-PHP/169106-2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first section of code when you use the if statement, you are checking to see if that one condition is true and then outputting your message.

A try catch block essentially works like this

```
try{
   //place code here that could potentially throw an exception
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  //We will catch ANY exception that the try block will throw

}
```

So you see that while your if statement is checking for a condition that you are anticipating, the try catch block will detect anything that goes wrong, even those things that you don't anticipate.
Therefore, when debugging you can alter the code in the catch block to deal with exceptions as you see fit

See the PHP docs for more information about exceptions
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I assumed that the only error that could take place was the connection error checked by $db->connect_error. Just wondering what other type of exceptions could be detected by the try/catch when trying to connect to a database.

Comment: When you use a catch block with Exception $e, this will catch any exception that is thrown, even if it is just the connection exception. I found this question that also may be of some use to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836693/how-to-use-throw-exception-in-mysql-database-connect

Comment: That's where I get confused. If I enter wrong parameters when trying to connect to the database (please see the update I added to my post) the catch block is not executed (no error is echoed). Is the connect error not treated as an exception? Thanks

Comment: If you see the link I posted to the other question regarding this type of exception, he combined the two methods by checking if a condition is true and if it is, throwing a new exception to be caught by the catch block. Try that

Answer (score 22):

If you need to catch exceptions on mysqli extension by use try/catch block, try this code (switch on exception mode instead of classic error reporting):

```
// Method 1:
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR;

// OR Method 2:
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

try {
    $db = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

[mysqli_sql_exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php)
[mysqli_driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php)

Answer (score -2):

Are you asking about what's the different with `$db->connect_error` and `try/catch`?

`$db->connect_error` mostly for the errors which we already knew (username incorrect, etc.)

and `try/catch` is about *system level*, once an error occur,

PHP will search for the nearest try/catch block,

once it catch something, PHP will still continue like nothing happened before,

but if you don't have any `try/catch` block and `set_exception_handler()` too,

PHP will just stop by the error.