# die() or try/catch when interacting with MySql database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, exception

A lot of tutorials and books I have been over and read have used the **die()** method to catch an exception when interacting with a local MySQL database

For example:

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die(mysql_error());
```

Would a try/catch block be more beneficial over the **die()** method or is that just the standard way that exception handling works with db connections?

Comment: when you use *try/catch* you will use **throw new Exception()** instead of *die()*

Comment: `try/catch` allows you to handle Exceptions cleanly, whereas `die()` is abrupt and rarely allows you to display user-friendly messages..... but `mysql_connect` doesn't throw any Exception, and the `MySQL_*` functiond are deprecated and won't exist in PHP for much longer

Comment: No, you can write your way to handle this exception as you like (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9836727/3615630)

Comment: use die in development. How would you like die if you were booking a flight on Travelocity ? Also, why in the world are you using mysql_* functions? It is the 21st century :>

Comment: Die quits the application at whatever point it was called. Don't do this in production, use the try catch and return a nice pretty error message so your users won't be left with a blank page or some cryptic php error message. Also, `mysql_*` functions have been depricated as of php 5.5.0, use `mysqli_*` or `pdo` instead.

Comment: Correction: a lot of **bad** tutorials and books use `die()`. It's not the job of the code that connects to the database to decide when the application ends or how it reacts when the database is not accessible. Forget about `die()`, you don't need it. The place where the function [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) (the real name of `die()`) is needed is just after `header('Location:');` if you don't use a framework and handle these things manually. Apart from that, the usage of `exit()` is a code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or die()` is an extremely primitive way to "handle" errors and only for examples or debugging at best. In practice, it depends on how you handle your errors. You may want to `return false` from a function call or you may want to throw your own exception instead; e.g.:

```
if (!$con = mysql_connect(..)) {
    throw new DatabaseConnectionError(mysql_error());
}
```

`try..catch` will do exactly *nothing* with `mysql`, since `mysql` never throws any exceptions. It only ever returns `false` on failure.

You will have to have your own *error handling strategy*. You'll probably want to log errors and display a user friendly error page instead of cryptic error messages. `mysql` is not concerned with that part. It only gives you a way to check whether an operation was successful or not (check if it returns `false`); what you do with this information is up to you. `die` kills the entire application and at least doesn't allow the problem to propagate further; but it certainly does not display any user friendly error pages.

Having said all this, `mysql` is old and deprecated. If you'd use something newer like PDO instead, it *can* properly throw exceptions itself.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_connect method does not throw exceptions and thus `die()` is used by many applications to terminate when there is no connection available. 
You can use the solution mentioned here: [how to use throw exception in mysql database connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836693/how-to-use-throw-exception-in-mysql-database-connect/9836727#9836727)

Included for completeness:

```
try
{
    if ($db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Alternatively use the new and more OOP styled database access: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

The reason a lot of applications uses `die` is from the fact that they are so reliant on the database that continuing without a connection is utterly fruitless.

**Edit** As mentioned in the comments, the code example above is for illustrational purposes. Catching right after throwing is pointless.

Comment: This is also sample code at best, just like `or die()`, since you'd never `try..catch` an exception immediately this way.

Comment: *"and thus die() is needed"* - No, `die()` it's not needed. It's not the responsibility of the code that connects to the database to decide how the application should behave when the database is not accessible.