# Cannot Connect to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
<?php
//Step1
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','[mypassword]','users')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I am just trying to connect to my MySQL database. It is administered using phpMyAdmin. I am very unfamiliar with MySQL and I have never used it before. [mypassword] is the password I use to successfully connect to mySQL from the Mac terminal. "users" is a name of a table I have created in phpMyAdmin. I am using cPanel. I keep on getting the error:

> Error connecting to mySQL server.

In phpMyAdmin it says `Server: localhost:3306.` I have tried for a very long time to fix this problem but with no results. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried the following:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "[myPassword]";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=users", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

After visiting the webpage it says

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Try using: `or die(mysqli_error($db))`, this will show you the reason for the failure, or even `mysqli_connect_error()`

Comment: *Error connecting to mySQL server* is obviously your own error message from the shown code. [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) may possibly produce more specific information about the problem.

Comment: I tried "or die(mysqli_error('localhost'));" and it didn't say anything on the webpage.

Comment: No, pass it the `$db` object. Exact line of code I posted.

Comment: @Matt Clark I tried it with the exact line of code that you posted. On the webpage it says nothing.

Comment: Search for that error message from PDO on SO.  You'll probably get the info you need among the first few hits.

Comment: Okay, try the second one then: [`mysqli_connect_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php). Follow the example given on this page.

Comment: I tried your second one above. Now, on the webpage it says Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your mySql instance is up.  You can download sequelpro and use that to connect to your mySQL.  If that doesn't work then its a mysql setting/config that is wrong.

Comment: On my Mac in System Preferences it says that there is an active instance of mySQL.

Comment: have you tried sequelpro or mysqlworkbench to connect to your db?  Basically were trying to isolate if this is PHP issue or installation issue

Comment: I have downloaded and installed mySQLWorkBench. It says Local Instance 3306. When I click on it, it says "Cannot Connect to Database Server." It also says "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so."

Comment: when you installed mysql you should have selected old authentication or simple something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch to handle errors on the connection proccess, but i strongly advise you to use PDO by alternative from mysqli [PDO Book](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Use something like this:

```
<?php
    try
    {
        if ($db = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db))
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

And check if the code print some connection error.

Reference: [how to use throw exception in mysql database connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836693/how-to-use-throw-exception-in-mysql-database-connect)

Comment: I just tried this. On the webpage it said "Unable to connect."

Comment: This will not show the reason for the connection failure. Like OPs code, this will only show that an error has occurred. `mysqli_connect` is not throwing any exception, but is simply failing. It has its own methods to retrieve the failure reasons.

Comment: @MattClark thats why i advised him to use PDO instead of mysqli_ it has better security and more flexibility with error handling.

Comment: I have tried the PDO method (I added to my original post above). It also gives an error.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not on your code but on mysql server... could you please try to connect via terminal?

Comment: Connecting via terminal (as the root user with the same password I have been using) works succesfully. Connecting with my code above still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";

   // Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

   // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   echo "Connected successfully";
  ?>
```

[How to Connect to mysql using php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: I tried your code above with "root" as my username and with my password for the root user as the "password." On the webpage, it gave me the following error: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Comment: @Everett are you using the right password? it seems like your password is wrong

Comment: The password I am using is the same one that I use to start an instance in my Mac terminal of mySQL as the root user.

Comment: does your password contains [myspasssword] brackets or it is without brackets myspassword?

Comment: It is without brackets. It is a password simply such as MyPassword

Comment: so try without brackets @Everett hopefully it will work

Comment: sorry for the confusion. This whole time I have been trying it without brackets.

Comment: @Everett No problem.Happy coding