# why doesn't mysql autocommit gets disabled?

Tags: mysql

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hStJK.png)

I am trying to disable autocommit. But it never gets off. I tried different methods.

```
   set autocommit=0;
   set autocommit='OFF';
```

Also, I edited my.cnf file in [client] section

```
   init-command='set autocommit=0'
   init-command='set autocommit='OFF''
```

Also, set global didn't work.

```
   set global autocommit=0;
   set global autocommit='OFF';
```

None of these really worked. Please help me how to turn off this autocommit thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn off autocommit for a MySQL client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280465/how-do-i-turn-off-autocommit-for-a-mysql-client)

Comment: Sorry Sir @doug . I don't see using a third party tool as a solution, I want the root cause and command line fix. No offense.

Answer (score 1):

Do not edit **[client]** section for this.

Try by edit **[mysqld]** or **[mysql]** section of my.cnf for this change.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot png it looks like

```
set global autocommit='OFF';
```

was run twice and 'set autocommit='OFF' wasn't run.

If that is the case then

```
show global variables like '%autocommit%';
```

should report the global autocommit as OFF, while

```
show variables like '%autocommit%';
```

can still report autocommit as ON.

In testing with DELETE followed by a ROLLBACK, the local autocommit setting overrides the global autocommit setting.